# C# timers and/or lock use for updating dashboard widgets

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, timer, signalr

I am building a real-time dashboard with multiple widgets using SignalR in an ASP.NET environment. After all widgets have loaded their default data, each widget needs to update its data independently. This means I am using multiple timers to update their data, which is coming out of the database.

Now my question is what is the best way to use the timers in above situation, and how can I make sure it's thread safe

This is code I'm using now:

```
public static void Init(){      

    Stopwatch.Start();

    _timer = new Timer(_ =>
    {
        if (_updating)
        {
            return;
        }
        _updating = true;

        try
        {
            var timeDiffSecs = Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            Stopwatch.Restart();

            if (timeDiffSecs <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            //DoMyActionForUpdate
        }
        finally
        {
            _updating = false;
        }
    }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using for your GUI - WPF, Windows Forms, etc?

Comment: What kind of timer?  If it is a `DispatcherTimer` or Windows.Forms.Timer, it will run on the UI thread...

Comment: @dsolimano He said he's using SignalR and ASP.NET.  No GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Both `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer` invoke the `Elapsed` event and callback (respectively) with a thread pool thread. (you haven't detailed which one you're using) This means it will be (or at least could be) running on a different thread than any other timer.  This is the same as if you started multiple threads--you need to make these routines thread-safe.

Regardless of how these threads got started, the technique is the same.  Any data that could be shared between threads that isn't atomically accessible needs to be synchronized with other threads.  this is typically done with the `lock` keyword.  You haven't provide any code that seems to use any shared data; but, you do mention access to a database.  If you've got a shared connection to the database, you'll have to make sure only one thread at a time uses that connection.  For example:

```
lock(locker)
{
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();}
}
```

This shows the use of a field named "locker".  You'll need to create this (just an `Object`) and share that amongst all the threads in play.

If you provide more detail about what you're doing, specifically; someone might be able to provide a more detailed answer.